# Comparing SNMP OID in Python script

Tags: python, linux, snmp

I am very new to Python and I have an existing script which is simulated to behave as an SNMP agent responding to the get requests. It does the following functionality:

1. Collect an SNMP get request
2. Compare the length of the request
3. Send out a defined string as a response

This works as expected.

Now I need to enhance this script to make sure it checks the OID sent in the request and send a different response based on the OID. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what for the OIDs are in.  If you have a string like `1.2.3.4`, then you can simply compare the strings directly.  However, it is more useful to split the OID into a list of integers:

```
>>> oidstr = '1.2.3.4'
>>> oid = [int(x) for x in oidstr.split('.')]
```

You can compare the list equality as well.

If you have a binary string like `b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'`, then you can convert it to a list of integers using a similar comprehension - `oid = [x for x in oidbin]` since a binary string is iterable.